# enclose networking cable without splice

Tags: data-wiring

I paid an electrician to run cat6 between our house and home office in the back.  On one end he left the wiring exposed.  Is there a way to enclose this wire without splicing?

This is in the south and the conduit running between the 2 buildings is buried 2 feet underground.

[image]

Comment: With low voltage wire/cable you are free to do almost anything with it, not like house voltage where you must go by code.  Can make a nice box/cover in any nice shape you want.

Comment: Ok, do you know if box covers can be put around without splicing?

Comment: Why splice?  Just make a nice box to fit over everything(pipe and wire).  It is low voltage wire so no one who makes regulations cares.  If talking about where a box fits onto the wall, can make a hole with an open slot to slide over the wire.

Comment: That sounds awesome.  I suppose I need to find a small piece of split conduit that is UV/water resistant.

Comment: What's with the cut end?

Comment: They originally did the job with the wire ending on the building.  They then ran 2 wires from network panel to panel inside the buildings.

Comment: They ran some cables but not all… why? "Ship spoiled for a ha'porth of tar." Classic 'Friday afternoon' job; couldn't wait to get out of there.

Comment: The cut wire is abandoned.  The 2 other wires make the full run.

Comment: You can always cut open PVC junction boxes and conduit to place them around your existing wiring, then use adhesive sealant to reform the sections into a watertight enclosure system.

Comment: Any chance you're able to pull the excess cable inside the house or office and deal with the loops there?

Comment: unfortunately the walls have just been insulated and sheet rocked.  I don't think it is worth pulling 160 feet to the main house.